# What could be the reason for an overheating Arduino? [using TWO different power supplies]

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, analysis

I'm tinkering a bit with a new printed circuit board I made and I already lost two boards (one ESP32 and one Arduino WiFi 1010) and I'm stumped because I don't even know where to start to look for a cause - it just doesn't make sense to me. Let me explain...

Here is the circuit diagram with a portion marked that I believe to be unrelated to what happened (I might be wrong):

[image]

(power supply set to `24V` and `0.1A`, the thing in the middle [microcontroller] is an `ATTiny2313`, `WAGO` is a wire-to-board connector)

What's a bit sketchy I would say is that the ground of the Arduino WiFi (which is provided via USB) is connected to my floating lab power supply. It also has an earthing terminal as in the picture, but it is not connected to anything.

The laptop is running on battery, so it is not connected to mains voltage in *any* way.

Now I can (sadly) only recall what happened in terms of when I realized (through coincidence) that my Arduino got unusually hot *. So hot in fact, I'm pretty sure it's done (I used it as an ISP programmer and now the arduino is not recognized anymore).

*this happened not immediately but after some time ; I can't tell how long.

Anyway, this is less about the dead Arduino (and ESP) but more about what went wrong because, as previously stated, I have no idea where to even begin looking for something that might have caused this.

The DC-DC converter *might* have something to do with it, although I can't imagine how it might have damaged my Arduino.

The problem is, I would like to investigate (i.e. replicate) what happened, but I don't want to risk losing another Arduino Board because they are really expensive (+40$).

Why do I not understand what happened?

1.) I only connected GROUND between the two circuits, so it cannot (likely) be something to do with the +24V rail or +3.3V rail.

2.) MISO, MOSI and SCK are I/O pins that I don't think can provide that much current to my Arduino (my Microcontroller did not get hot at all).

3.) RESET is a bit different since IT IS connected to the +3.3V rail but through a 4.7k resistor.

In the end, I'm **really** hoping I'm missing something obvious here.

Any pointers or common pitfalls that one might fall into when using a USB powered device with another device that isn't on the same supply rail?

Edit: And even if you can't explain what happened, do you have any ideas on how I could (potentially) replicate my circuit in a *"safe"* or *"safer"* way?

Comment: The schematic is not showing up for me. There is an image, but it's blank.

Comment: I can see it. However, if you can't: here's an link to a site I uploaded it to just now: https://picul.de/view/QgB .

Comment: Funny that the only part you think is sketchy is actually mandatory. Connecting grounds of different chips/boards that is.

Comment: When troubleshooting, always, without exception, confirm the supplies are working as expected (the proper voltage), and the supply connections are also at the right level (connections on the chips and modules too).   While there, probe the gnd pins as well.

Comment: When you say fail, do they heat up, smoke, sparks, flames or do they go dead silently? What current do you observe on your lab power supply? What voltage do you measure on the 3.3 V rail?

Comment: The usual suspect is some kind of short circuits, including accidental short circuits through grounds, but you are using floating ground for everything so that can't have been the problem. Or connecting +24V to the Arduino by mistake, but +24V only goes to the converter so that wasn't the problem either. I think even shorting the data pins on most Arduinos won't cause them to get hot (it sometimes breaks the pin so still don't do it).

Comment: @winny I'm sorry, I will think of a better title. When I say fail, I noticed that my Arduino got unbelievably hot. I glanced at my power supply and didn't see great current **at all**. I even set the current limit to 100mA as a precaution. My Arduino didn't go up in smoke or flames - just very hot. Everything else was cool to the touch.

Comment: What I have to add though is that I had something similar happen in the past with another Arduino board that went up in smoke by just plugging in into my MacBook. I measured the USB Bus Voltage and it read 20V. Apparently Apple cheaped out on the PD (PowerDelivery) feature a bit and I am using a simply USB-C to USB-A adapter for connecting it to my laptop. However, I think that was with my older MacBook Pro Model (2017) and not with my current 2021 M1 Model.

Comment: @winny I measured a voltage (on the arduino) of about 1V **after** the incident (GND <> VCC). Normally it should be around 3.3V. But that isn't really useful, I already know the board is dead. I didn't think of measuring _anything_ I just quickly unplugged everything.

Comment: I notice at least two pins on the microcontroller are not connected. If they are digital inputs, they might be able to float to an undefined logic level where they could draw excess supply current, or perhaps oscillate. You might also try monitoring supply current to the parts that are overheating and failing. Maybe a 22 ohm resistor and a BJT with an LED that will light if more than about 30 mA is being drawn, and you could add an optocoupler to trip a latching relay that disconnects power.

Comment: @Marco Having a USB-C outputing 20V without requesting it would kill every standard 5V device, so I am quite sure Apple did not cheaped out on the Power Delivery feature, as we'd surely had heard about it if Apple made non-standard devices which are not Type-C compliant and kill Arduinos or whatnot. But yeah, your two devices use different supplies. That's a bad thing unless you design for it.

Comment: @Justme I don't want to go off-topic here but IIRC Apple only has three thunderbolt controllers for four ports (2017 model). This means two ports share one thunderbolt controller. It has been a while but I think when I connected Power to my MacBook Pro it would spit out 20V out of the neighbouring port: requested or not, just flat out 20V.

Comment: A 5 V crowbar on the USB power connection should protect the Arduino if the voltage somehow goes to 20V or anything fatal to the components. Also, as mentioned, having two separate power supplies can cause problems with synchronization of the two circuits. I think I smell a rotten Apple! :)

Comment: @Justme _Funny that the only part you think is sketchy is actually mandatory. Connecting grounds of different chips/boards that is._ I know that it is mandatory, but I also know about ground loops. And ground loops aren't a good thing. Now that PStechPaul mentioned it as well, I'm intrigued because I also believe the root of the problem lies in using two different power supplies.

Comment: @winny I have updated the title - I hope it is satisfactory now.

Comment: @Marco And as an extension to that, what happens if only 50% of the system is powered up? Either Arduino or ESP32? And the other one is unpowered? What do you think happens if one MCU has 3.3V on IO pin which is connected to another MCU that's unpowered?

Comment: @Justme I'm sorry I just have to ask straight away, is it a _bad_ idea to program a powered circuit? (i.e. a circuit that is not powered by the programmer)? (With the _above_ setup). I mean, I did observe that my board got a little power even when it shouldn't be on - possibly, as you said, through the I/O pin of the Arduino. I honestly didn't think much of it when I saw it but that isn't a good thing. Should I use diodes?

Comment: Much better. Thank you.

Comment: If something is heating up and your lab power supply does not show high current, it needs to be supplied from elsewhere. In your setup, the only thing remaining is the USB.

Answer (score 1):

Quite some time ago I had encountered a similar issue with the Arduino Mega board where the USB connection could back-feed the external supply circuit through a MOSFET body diode on their PCB.  This cause various issues for me...

My solution was to remove a SMT fuse that was originally in-line with the 5Vbus USB input and connect the in-circuit side of the fuse pad to my external 5V supply.

Perhaps something similar is going on with the Arduino Wifi board?

See the note at B3 in the print below.

[image]

Comment: But in this case the Arduino does not have two power supplies connected.

Comment: I was about to comment what @user253751 said. It's a good thing to know, but as stated in my post, only GND and the SPI (incl. RESET) pins are connected. I'll probably take the risk and re-do the setup exactly as shown in my post to see if I can reproduce the issue. I'm a bit worried that I won't be able to reproduce the issue though. It could also have been a wiring mistake, although I see the chances of that being the case to be really low since the circuit has worked all day without an issue. To add to that, a similar thing happened to my ESP (but not connected the same way as the Arduino).